# FILE opening code in C. I need an explanation why this code gives different outputs when run several times

Tags: c, file, memory-address

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void){
    FILE *fp = fopen("temp.txt", "we");
    printf("%p\n", fp);
    return 0;
}
```

this code gives the following different outputs:
0x19ee260
0x1ef9260
0xbde8260
.
.
.
I need an explanation concerning the memory.

Comment: Why do you expect it to give the same output each time?

Comment: A `FILE *` doesn't point to the *file*, but to a structure with information used to access it.  That can be in different memory locations from one run to another.

Comment: `fp` is a `FILE *`. The address of `fp` is a stack location. The stack address range, as well as other memory segments, is randomized in many modern systems via Address Space Layout Randomization (ASLR) as a security feature.

Comment: BT I'm not aware of an `e` mode as in `"we"`

Comment: @h0r53 that's the distinction between the location of the file pointer variable, and what it points to.

Comment: @h0r53 `fp` points most likely one some heap memory. But the `fp` variable itself is most likely on the stack (at least on all architectures I've came across in my life).

Comment: Very true, `printf` in this instance is printing the location of the buffer containing the data of `temp.txt`, not the location of `fp` on the stack. Either way both locations are likely randomized as a result of ASLR. IIRC the actual behavior of `fopen` is OS dependent when it comes to actually memory mapping versus creating a file handle or etc.

Comment: @Husseini, implementation specifics aside, the memory location that the file is loaded into is somewhat irrelevant in practical usage, as you simply can use `fp` to consistently access that data. This is generally handled by the kernel/OS under the hood. In practice, it would be very bad if `fopen` loaded files into predictable locations in memory, as many low-level exploits could take advantage of this. One such example would be loading binary instructions into a known location and finding a way to manipulate the instruction pointer to reference that location via a buffer overflow or similar.

Comment: @Jabberwocky sorry its a mistake. It should be "wr" not "we"

Comment: @h0r53 _"printf in this instance is printing the location of the buffer containing the data of temp.txt,"_: no, this is wrong. `p` points to some internal structure the library uses to read data from the open file. The details of the internal structure are irrelevant and they can vary from implementation to implementation.

Comment: If you want reading and writing, then rather than "wr", shouldn't it be either "w+" or "r+" (depending on whether you want to keep the existing file contents)?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to [Address Space Layout Randomization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization). The `FILE` structure that `fopen()` returns a pointer to is in the process's heap memory, and ASLR means that the location of the heap will be different each time you run a program.

Comment: But even without ASLR it is not guaranteed that the program always prints the same value, is it?

Comment: Not guaranteed, but likely.